# Pointers to elements of a C++ class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a **C++** class *c_image* which contains a vector of pointers to elements of class *c_pixel*:

```
class c_image {

    public:
        vector<shared_ptr<c_pixel>> pixel;
    ...
};
```

Class *c_pixel* elements contain an element *Z* of type double:

```
class c_pixel {

    public:
        double Z;
    ...
};
```

However, they are extended with class *c_pixel_pv*, which contains *pv*, an array of three elements of type double:

```
class c_pixel_pv : public c_pixel {

    public:
        double pv[3];
    ...
};
```

Class *c_image* also has a function *filter*

```
vector<double> c_image::filter(???) {
        ...
    };
```

which will take as input a pointer to the elements *Z* or *pv[0]* or *pv[1]* or *pv[2]*.

But I have no idea how to point to these elements. I don't even know if it is possible to point, for example, only to *pv[0]* elements. I have no clue how to begin with this problem. Can anybody help me?

Comment: would the function behave diffrently if it was z or pv[0] or... ?

Comment: Won't it be just `double*`? After all, `Z` or `pv[..]` are all doubles!

Comment: You can't have a "member pointer" that can point "maybe inside a member or maybe not" (note that `pv[0]` is not a member of `c_pixel_pv`, only `pv` is). Your question raises a lot of other questions though, like: why are the pixels shared? What is the image sharing these pixels with? And is there a point to images being able to contain a mixture of `c_pixel` and `c_pixel_pv`?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi No, exactly the same

Comment: @molbdnilo It is a complex structure of classes, but necessary if you know the whole problem.

Comment: filter function will filter on what? For c_pixel type pixels it will be on Z obviously. But for c_pixel_pv type pixels will it be on all three of pv[0] pv[1] and pv[2] or will the caller provide a parameter indicating on which value it wants to filter, like filter(1) will filter on pv[1] or filter(2) will filter on pv[2] etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could (and probably should) use *polymorphism* and have a virtual member function in the `c_pixel` class that is overridden in the `c_pixel_pv` class. This member function performs whatever operation is needed using the correct member variables, and is called from `c_image::filter`.

Comment: The function c_image::filter can be, for example, a median smoothing filter which, for each pixel of the image, calculates the median value of the pixels around it. In this case, an individual element c_pixel doesn't have all the information needed to smooth it. That's why I think that the filter cannot run as a function on c_pixel.

Comment: @Medicalphysicist but then that is a choice you should make, i mean if median smoothing is not applicable for c_pixel, then do not include that pixel in the result set.

Comment: @Medicalphysicist You *can* use e.g. `dynamic_cast` to check if a pointer is a pointer to the base class or a child class, but that leads to [*code smell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and code that will become hard to read, understand and maintain. Maybe you should have two "filter" functions instead, one for each type of pixel. That could be a borderline code smell, but at least it's better. I think what you really need to do is to rethink your design, do you really need to different pixel types? Can a single image have both types simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

The OOP concept - *polymorphism* would come in handy now. A virtual member function (A virtual member is a member function that can be redefined in a derived class, while preserving its calling properties, through references) in the `c_pixel` class, overridden in the derived `c_pixel_pv` class, could perform the operation you need with the correct variables.

You will need to call this member function from the `vector<double> c_image::filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function rather than a pointer:

```
using Selector = std::function<double(const c_pixel&)>;

vector<double> c_image::filter(Selector select) {
    // Trivial example that just copies
    vector<double> result;
    result.reserve(pixel.size());
    for (auto pix: pixel)
    {
        result.push_back(select(*pix)); 
    }
    return result;
};

double z(const c_pixel& p)
{
    return p.Z;
}

c_image image;
// ...
vector<double> = image.filter(z);
```

But you'd need some way to discriminate between the different types of pixel, like a tag byte or a virtual function (so they would take up even more room and you already have a lot of overhead).

If you don't need to mix pixel types in an image, you could use a template class, templated on the pixel type.
Then you could get rid of the runtime pixel discrimination.
(To be honest, it's difficult to picture how a function like `filter` would handle pixels of a type that doesn't have the element it's supposed to use.)